# Firefox Extensions - best practices

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I've been writing a Firefox extension, but have recently read a few articles explaining that it's bad practice to avoid variable name clashes by simple appending the application name to the front of the variable.

Unfortunately I have been doing this. What is the best practice instead? I assume it's to somehow namespace the variables. I've found various articles about wrapping everythign in a master object, but sadly no examples of this.

Can anyone point me to a good tutorial, or even a simple extension, that uses best-practices?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Peter Michaux [explains Javascript namespacing](http://peter.michaux.ca/articles/javascript-namespacing) very nicely.

Answer (score 5):

You can have a look at this video from Google tech, which explains best practices for JavaScript coding which is a main part of Firefox extension development

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0LKDImgRfrg

[alt text http://0.gvt0.com/ThumbnailServer2?app=vss&contentid=4d0ae57a8484fdf8&offsetms=275000&itag=w160&hl=en&sigh=GnGo87Drht4wi2JvP1L0PtvKT4M](http://0.gvt0.com/ThumbnailServer2?app=vss&contentid=4d0ae57a8484fdf8&offsetms=275000&itag=w160&hl=en&sigh=GnGo87Drht4wi2JvP1L0PtvKT4M)

Answer (score 2):

Not strictly related to your original question about namespacing, but https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/how-to/extension-development has a link about that as well as about other extension best practices.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks very much for taking the time to answer - there's some useful stuff there for sure.

I also found this guide, which is pretty comprefensive:

http://robertnyman.com/2009/01/24/how-to-develop-a-firefox-extension/